# Separate Nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I'm probably overthinking this, but I have a JSON array with multiple levels of nested JSON objects that looks like this:

```
var OldJSON =  
    {  
   "data":{  
      "shifts":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":1234,
               "entry_time":"2012-06-11 16:06:04",
               "attendance_id":1
            },
            {  
               "id":4321,
               "entry_time":"2014-07-23 17:29:04",
               "attendance_id":2
            }
         ]
      },
      "sites":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":4321,
               "name":"John Doe",
               "type":"field",
               "bases":{  
                  "data":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1234,
                        "type":"field",
                        "active":false
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":4321,
                        "type":"field",
                        "active":true
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "id":1234,
               "name":"Jill Doe",
               "type":"field",
               "bases":{  
                  "data":[  
                     {  
                        "id":1234,
                        "type":"field",
                        "active":false
                     },
                     {  
                        "id":4321,
                        "type":"field",
                        "active":true
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is Separate the 'base' object out of the 'sites' object and reorganize the JSON so it looks like this:

```
var NewJSON = 
{  
   "data":{  
      "shifts":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":1234,
               "entry_time":"2012-06-11 16:06:04",
               "attendance_id":1
            },
            {  
               "id":4321,
               "entry_time":"2014-07-23 17:29:04",
               "attendance_id":2
            }
         ]
      },
      "sites":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":4321,
               "name":"John Doe",
               "type":"field"
            },
            {  
               "id":1234,
               "name":"Jill Doe",
               "type":"field"
            }
         ]
      },
      "bases":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":1234,
               "type":"field",
               "active":false
            },
            {  
               "id":4321,
               "type":"field",
               "active":true
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using Javascript and Angular in my project along with underscore. So ideally the solution would utilize one of those three. Everything I've come up with looks ugly, so I'm wondering if there is a simple way of doing something like this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: For starters, your normalizer should live in the `transformResponse` function of your `$resource`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would help in this situation?

Comment: I'm saying that's where your solution should go, if you haven't already put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this code, too ugly?

```
var data = JSON.parse(/*Your JSON */).data;
var bases = [];
var i;
var sites = data.sites.data;
var len = sites.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var site = sites[i];
    var base = site.data.bases;

    bases.push(base.date);

    delete site.data.bases;
}

data.bases = {data : Array.prototype.concat.apply([], bases) };
```

Comment: Thanks! looks good to me, except that bases is an array instead of `bases{data:[]}`

Comment: Sorry about that, how about now?